# Can't delete MailGun bounces?

Tags: python, mailgun, email-bounces

In the MailGun backend, I've noticed a "Not delivering to previously bounced address" error:

[image]

This is probably because, at that time, the email address was not properly set up yet, but now it is. Therefore, I'd like to remove the address `kurt@hicleo.com` from the list of previously bounced addresses.

Following https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-bounces.html#bounces, I've implemented a `get_bounces()` method for our sender domain, `mg.startwithlucy.com`:

```
    In [1]: import requests

    In [2]: def get_bounces():
       ...:     return requests.get('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.startwithlucy.com
       ...: /bounces', auth=('api', '<our_api_key>') 
       ...:     )
       ...: 

    In [3]: response = get_bounces()

    In [4]: response.status_code
    Out[4]: 200

    In [6]: import json

    In [7]: content = json.loads(response.content)

    In [14]: next(item for item in content['items'] if item['address'] == 'kurt@hicleo.com')
    Out[14]: 
    {'MessageHash': '0f35b8112739c23d996bece18755de105a8422ad',
     'address': 'kurt@hicleo.com',
     'code': '550',
     'created_at': 'Thu, 07 Jun 2018 17:48:28 UTC',
     'error': 'No Such User Here'}
```

Next, I defined a `delete_bounce(address)` function and called it for `kurt@hicleo.com`. However, I still see the corresponding email address showing up in the result of `get_bounces()`:

```
In [21]: def delete_bounce(address):
    ...:     return requests.delete(f'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.startwithlucy.com/{address
    ...: }', auth=('api', '<our_api_key>'))
    ...:     

In [22]: delete_response = delete_bounce('kurt@hicleo.com')

In [23]: delete_response.status_code
Out[23]: 200

In [24]: delete_response.content
Out[24]: b'Mailgun Magnificent API'

In [25]: response = get_bounces()

In [26]: response.status_code
Out[26]: 200

In [27]: content = json.loads(response.content)

In [28]: kurt_bounces = [item for item in content['items'] if item['address'] == 'kurt@hicleo.
    ...: com']

In [29]: kurt_bounces
Out[29]: 
[{'MessageHash': '0f35b8112739c23d996bece18755de105a8422ad',
  'address': 'kurt@hicleo.com',
  'code': '550',
  'created_at': 'Thu, 07 Jun 2018 17:48:28 UTC',
  'error': 'No Such User Here'}]
```

What is going wrong here? This seems to me to be a correct Python implementation of the instructions in the API reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have left `bounces` (between domain & address) out of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Also, bounces can easily be deleted using MailGun's UI, in the 'Suppressions' tab as shown here:

[image]